# Module over a noncommutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am a beginner at Rings and Modules. One exercise that I try in modules asks the following:

If the ring $R$ is a non-commutative ring and $V$ is a $R$-module, then it is not a good idea to define $vr=rv$; where $r\in R$ and $v\in V$

My attempt:

I am not sure where I understood this problem well or not. I tried to make some contradiction using the four axioms (in definition) needed for a $R$-module $V$ but could not conclude a contradiction.

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: The question sounds rather odd. Have you quoted it exactly? i suspect it is asking you to show that you can't turn a left module into a right module just by defining the right action of $R$ by $vr = rv$, where $rv$ denotes the outcome of the left action of $r \in R$ on $v \in V$. To prove this, you need to look at a specific example: you won't get a contradiction from the axioms, because the axioms don't preclude the possibility that $R$ is commutative (in which case, the construction works).

Comment: @RobArthan, It is the same question and is from Artin's first edition chapter 12 modules. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Artin wrote more than one book. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @RobArthan, Algebra (first edition) by Michael Artin.

Comment: I only have the second edition of Michael Artin's Algebra to hand. It doesn't seem to contain an exercise like the one you quote or to deal with non-commutative rings in general. Is your book by Emil Artin rather than Michael Artin?

Comment: @RobArthan, It is by Michael Artin's but first edition. You can find it here "http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=algebra+artin&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def"

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring. Suppose $V$ is a left $R$-module equipped with the operation $\cdot$. Suppose we defined $V$ also as a right $R$-module equipped with the operation $*$ defined as $v*r:=r\cdot v$. Let $r,s\in R$ and let $v\in V$. Then we have

$$(rs)\cdot v=r\cdot (s\cdot v),$$

since $V$ is a left $R$-module. Since $V$ is a right $R$-module, we have

$$v*(rs)=(v*r)*s\implies (rs)\cdot v=s\cdot(r\cdot v).$$

We can equate these two to get

$$r\cdot (s\cdot v)=s\cdot (r\cdot v)\implies (rs)\cdot v=(sr)\cdot v.$$

Now, suppose $R=V=M_2(\mathbb Z)$, the $2\times 2$ matrices with integer coefficients. Take $v$ to be the identity matrix and $r,s$ to be any two matrices that don't commute.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is noncommutative, we talk about left and right modules.

If we have a two sided module where $rv=vr$ then we always get a commutative action: for any $r,s$ we have
$$(rs)v=r(sv)=r(vs)=(vs)r=v(sr)=(sr)v\,.$$